# PHP regex: zero or more whitespace not working

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I'm trying to apply a regex constraint to a Symfony form input. The requirement for the input is that the start of the string and all commas must be followed by zero or more whitespace, then a `#` or `@` symbol, except when it's the empty string.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell the constraint to use `preg_match_all` instead of just `preg_match`, but it does have the ability to negate the match. So, I need a regular expression that `preg_match` will NOT MATCH for the given scenario: `any string containing the start of the string or a comma, followed by zero or more whitespace, followed by any character that is not a # or @ and is not the end of the string`, but will match for everything else. Here are a few examples:

```
preg_match(..., '');              // No match
preg_match(..., '#yolo');         // No match
preg_match(..., '#yolo,  #swag'); // No match
preg_match(..., '#yolo,@swag');   // No match
preg_match(..., '#yolo, @swag,'); // No match

preg_match(..., 'yolo');        // Match
preg_match(..., 'swag,#yolo');  // Match
preg_match(..., '@swag, yolo'); // Match
```

I would've thought for sure that `/(^|,)\s*[^@#]/` would work, but it's failing in every case with 1 or more spaces and it appears to be because of the asterisk. If I get rid of the asterisk, `preg_match('/(^|,)\s[^@#]/', '#yolo, @swag')` does not match (as desired) when there's exactly once space, but as as soon as I reintroduce the asterisk it breaks for any quantity of spaces > 0.

My theory is that the regex engine is interpreting the second space as a character that is not in the character set `[@#]`, but that's just a theory and I don't know what to do about it. I know that I could create a custom constraint to use `preg_match_all` instead to get around this, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I think you need `'~(?:^|,)\s*+[^#@]~'`. Append `(?!$)` if you need the "not at the end of the string" condition.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works if I just follow the `*` with a `+` like in your example. Why is the `+` necessary?

Comment: It makes matching *possessive*, i.e. there is no backtracking into `\s*` pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:^|,)\s*+[^#@]~'
```

Here, the `+` symbol defines a `*+` [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) matching 0 or more occurrences of whitespace chars, and disallowing the regex engine to backtrack into `\s*` pattern if `[^@#]` cannot match the subsequent char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKdoIM/1).

**Details**

- `(?:^|,)` - either start of string or `,`
- `\s*+` - zero or more whitespace chars, possessively matched (i.e. if the next char is not matched with `[^#@]` pattern, the whole pattern match will fail)
- `[^@#]` - a negated character class matching any char but `@` and `#`.